# Supreme Court counting problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes, random-variables, recurrence-relations

Assume the Supreme Court currently has 6 conservative judges and 3 liberal judges. Furthermore, assume that currently the President and both houses of Congress are controlled by the liberal party. Assume that every 2 years there is an election for a new Congress and both houses have an independent 50-50 chance of being controlled by either party after each election. Furthermore, assume the Presidential election is every 4 years and as with Congress, there is a 50-50 chance that the next President will be liberal or conservative. Whenever both houses of Congress and the President are from the same party and the Court is controlled by the other party, they will always increase the number of Supreme Court judges to the smallest odd number such that their party seizes control of the Court. Sitting justices sometimes die unexpectedly and create an empty seat. When there is an empty seat, they are replaced by someone from the same ideology as the sitting President if it is in the first 3 years of the term or if it is in the fourth year of the term and the President is from the same party that controls the Senate. Otherwise, the seat remains empty until the next presidential election and the seat is replaced then by someone from the ideology of the new President. Assume all judges are 50 years old when appointed (including the current 9 judges sitting on the court). The hazard rate of death for each judge is constant over the next 40 years after appointment with 1% chance of death per year. If they reach 80 years of age, they will voluntarily retire as soon as they can be assured they will be replaced by someone with the same ideology. What's the expected number of conservative and liberal judges on the court in $t$ years? Time $0$ started when the current President was inaugurated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. It's well defined and not trivial. I don't understand why people would downvote the question.

I have not found an analytic solution, but I have a conjecture about the rate of growth.

Because of the rules, the size of the court can never decrease. So, there is theoretically a possibility that it reaches a finite size such that within each presidential term, enough judges die so that when they are replaced the ideology of the court (if it differs from the president's) is already flipped and there is no need to increase the size. It's not specified in the problem, but I am assuming that the increase in court size would occur as late as possible (at the end of the two year House term). In an extreme situation such as when you assume all judges always die within every two year House term, clearly there would never be any need to add justices. Maybe there is a finite mortality rate high enough that would also lead to a fixed point solution.

When the time is large, approximately half of the justices will be from each ideology, so we can focus on calculating the total number of justices.

As the problem is stated, it seems that the size of the court grows fairly quickly. Let $N(t)$ be the number of justices and let $X(t)={log(N(t))}^2$.
The expected value of $X(t)$ is approximately $-4.89+0.0254 t$ and the variance of $X(t)$ is approximately $-0.1997-0.001240 t+0.000008016 t^2$. Also $X(t)$ is approximately normally distributed. Hence,
$$N(t) \approx e^{\sqrt{X(t)}} \approx e^{\sqrt{-4.89+0.0254 t}}$$

The black dots show the observed mean and variance from simulations. The red curves show the curves defined by the predictions from the polynomials above.

[image]

[image]